# Images are not shown in React although the path is right

Tags: reactjs, path, utf

I have created a little test in react with dynamic content. Within a sidebar there is something like bootstrap collapses, containing lists with icons and names. The problem is that some images within "Natürlich" are not shown. These images are stored together with all the working ones and if I follow the link from the inspector the right images is at the right place.

I have some code going on to take the name of the list item and first remove the umlauts and then put it in between the link of the image as you can see here. This seems to work for all other images except the 3 missing within "Natürlich"

```
correctNames: function(warning) {
  if (warning) {
    var warningCorrected = warning.toLowerCase().replace(/\u00f6/g, 'oe').replace(/\u00e4/g, 'ae').replace(/\u00fc/g, 'ue').replace(/\u00df/g, 'ss');
    return warningCorrected
  }     
},


render: function() {
    var warnings = this.props.warningName;
    var isActive = this.state.warningState ? 'warning-active' : 'warning-inactive';
    return ( 
    <li className={'transition ' + isActive} onClick={this.activateWarning}>
    {this.correctNames()}
    <img src={'img/warning/' + this.correctNames(warnings) + '-active.png'} alt="" />
    <p>{warnings + " " + this.correctNames(warnings)}</p>
    </li>
    );
}
```

You can find the page [here](http://bettergood.de)

UPDATE!
It seems to be a problem with UTF-8 or something. While in my inspector the path is shown right, the error message is 
`kon%E2%80%8Bser%E2%80%8Bvie%E2%80%8Brungs%E2%80%8Bstoffe-active.png`

How can I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the source of my problem. The api actually returned the names like `Anti\u200boxi\u200bdations\u200bmit\u200btel` `\u200b` is used to tell the mobile app where to break words.

```
.replace(/\u200b/g, '')
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
src={`img/warning/${this.correctNames(warnings)}-active.png`}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: can you show the folder structure ? i think it should be `./img` or `../img` instead of `img`.

Comment: I tried both in the meantime. None is working. But all of my other images are shown perfectly and they are all stored in the same folder.

Comment: may be problem will be in your function `correctNames`, it will not be returning anything, check that also.

Comment: Again, this function goes over all the names. And all other images are shown perfectly. Also to check the result I show the corrected names directly beside the original names.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `webpack` you may need to use `require`  in your image source

```
render: function() {
    var warnings = this.props.warningName;
    var isActive = this.state.warningState ? 'warning-active' : 'warning-inactive';
    return ( 
    <li className={'transition ' + isActive} onClick={this.activateWarning}>
    {this.correctNames()}
    <img src={require(`'./img/warning/${this.correctNames(warnings)}-active.png'`)} alt="" />
    <p>{warnings + " " + this.correctNames(warnings)}</p>
    </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: When using this I get the error `Module not found: 'img/warning' in /Users/sinan/Desktop/React/better-good/src/standart`.

Comment: Try the updated answer. Also specify the src relative to the file

Comment: Still the same problem. `require` always seems to expect a module.